# Would this circuit interface be a safe interface between full duplex and half-duplex UARTs of different logic levels?

Tags: uart, serial, logic-level

I'm primarily a SW developer who dabbles with electronics. I needs to interface my SoC's HW full-duplex UART with an SDI-12 compliant sensor, without burning either of them and hopefully without wasting too much power. The following constraints are given:

- Full-duplex side operates on 3.3V, normal polarity (i.e. logic LOW is 0V and logic HIGH is 3.3V), has separate TX (output) and RX (input) pins.
- Half-duplex side operates anywhere between 3.5V-5.5V, inverted polarity, has a single TX/RX pin
- There vast majority of the time the line will be silent (i.e. the wire connecting to sensors TX/RX pin will be at 0V
- The wire leading to a sensors TX/RX pin might be long (just in case any funkiness of high parasitic inductance or something should change my design).

The circuit I drafted quickly:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fayEEm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In particular I'm curious if you had any comments about the choice of particular components and their values.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I'm aware of general logic level shifting with a MOSFET but in my question I'm most concerned about safety of such method and not wasting power, seeing that it involves a half-duplex serial so it might end up in situations where both sides try to drive it.

Answer (score 1):

That kind of level shifter is intended for open-collector/open-drain circuits only, in which the devices on either side can only actively pull the signal low, and rely on a passive pullup to pull it high.

Your circuit will work only if the inverter connected to "µC Tx", as well as the sensor itself, have open-collector/open-drain outputs.

Comment: So what happens when the inverter after µC Tx open-drains straight to ground while right side is driven high? Wouldn't that create a path of too little resistance from 5V sensor side TX -> M1 -> open-drain of the inverter -> ground?

Comment: That's why I said that they both have to be open-drain devices. If the sensor is not open-drain, there's no easy way to "fake it". You'll need a much more sophisticated interface adapter.